# Is the latest 2021 Pavilion Gaming Desktop Computer a rip off?

Tags: gaming, pc, desktop

I found a pc for 1200 bucks. But the specs seem off. only 400W power supply. bad processor. not enough ram. but I'm not sure if I'm just overthinking the quality of the pc. After all it is a nice gpu.

PC Build on NewEgg:

2021 Latest Pavilion Gaming Desktop Computer (AMD Ryzen 3 5300G, NVIDIA RTX 3060 Graphics Card, Windows 10 Home, 256GB NVMe SSD + 8GB DDR4 RAM, 400 Watt Power Supply) VR Ready PC

Link:
https://www.newegg.com/hp-tg01-pavilion-gaming/p/3D5-0005-00E50?Item=9SIA8S1FCB9512&quicklink=true

Comment: if this question isn't formated correctly. Please give suggestions on where to post this question.

Comment: nea, don't think so, but if you think so, you can build a pc yourself. But if you want a 3060, this may be a good way of getting one and ram/cpu can be upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why someone downvoted.  I think this is a great question.

The computer would normally be overpriced, but because of the silicon shortages, in 2021 it's actually a pretty good deal.  The only issue I have with it is being built by an OEM.  Typically if it's built by an OEM (such as Dell, HP, Lenovo, Acer, etc.), the parts are more proprietary so you won't be able to upgrade them like you could on a computer that is custom-built.  If you could spend a couple of hundred extra dollars, I would highly recommend either building a computer yourself, or ordering a custom-built machine from a large company (such as iBuyPower, CyberPowerPC, or Origin).

Some videos to check out before making a final decision:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gz7WMF4wWko

Make sure you watch all four videos in the series on the above one.  It has really good information about buying prebuilt gaming PCs from a variety of manufacturers (including HP).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P1w-y6e0vs8

This video has more information about HP specifically.